# Collection.find() very slow with other BDD Meteor React

Tags: performance, mongodb, meteor, reactjs, find

I'm working on an app with Meteor and React.
I'm trying to have the content of inventories_array from an external MongoDB database, but it's extremely slow. I wait 7 seconds, I have one object, I wait 5 seconds, two other objects, etc...

```
Spaces = new Mongo.Collection("Space");
Properties = new Mongo.Collection("Property");
Inventories = new Mongo.Collection("Inventory");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("Property");
    Meteor.subscribe("Space");
    Meteor.subscribe("Inventory");  
    Tracker.autorun(function() { 

        inventories_array = Inventories.find({quantityBooked: 2},{fields: {priceTaxExcl: 1, property: 1, space: 1}}).fetch();
    console.log(inventories_array);

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("Property", function () {
    return Properties.find();
  });

  Meteor.publish("Space", function () {
    return Spaces.find();
  });
  Meteor.publish("Inventory", function () {
    return Inventories.find();
  }); 
}
```

The Inventory Object:

```
{
 ...
 "property" : ObjectId("..."),
 "space" : ObjectId("..."),
 "quantityBooked":2,
 "priceTaxExcl":...,
 ...
}
```

I launch the app with `MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb meteor run`

Any ideas why it's so slow?

Comment: How big is your data set in Inventory/Inventories, as well as Space and Property?

Comment: for Inventory: 3 ObjectId, 1 Date, 4 int
for Property and Space, they are big but I have only their ID in inventory.

I have tested with another Collection which is smaller (3 String an 2 Dates) and I have the same problem

Comment: I mean how many records are in your collections?

Comment: A lot. 2148 Inventory, 51 Property, 96 Space but I have tested with {limit: 5} on my find() and it's still slow

Comment: sorry for all the questions, but did you set the limit on the client side or server side query?

Comment: And it's the same with a Collection of 10 elements

Comment: no worries, thank you for helping me. On the client side

Comment: If you set a limit on the client side, it won't improve performance as the server will still be passing the entire collection back to the client. All 2148 inventory objects are being sent to your client (potentially very frequently). It is pretty difficult to debug with us talking like this, so I would recommend installing Kadira: https://kadira.io/ It's free and you can start getting stats about your app in 10 minutes, and it should show you where your performance bottlenecks are. You could also try running your Inventories.find() query in the chrome debug console to see how long it takes too

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your network tab in the inspector you'll see all the data flowing from the server to the client for each subscription and you'll be able to judge both how large it is and how long it takes.

I'd recommend at a first step that you alter your `Inventory` publication as follows:

```
Meteor.publish("Inventory", function () {
  if ( this.userId ){ // only return data if we have a logged-in user
    return Inventories.find({quantityBooked: 2},{fields: {priceTaxExcl: 1, property: 1, space: 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

This way your server is only sending the required fields from the required documents (assuming you only want docs where `{quantityBooked: 2}`.